# Problem with local module detection. python aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

I have this project structure:

```
project-root
│
├── bot/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
│
└── venv/
    ├── run.py
```

**init**.py initializes the main.py file, but the run.py file does not see it and returns me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\AfishaBot\venv\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bot import start_bot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot'
```

of course it is not the whole project, in other files the same problem.

I can even go to all root files in the PayCharm editor for imports and it will transfer me to the necessary files, but this does not happen when I start it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.